# Oracle Proc with date criteria runs but doesn't update

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm having a probem executing a Oracle stored procedure through PHP.  I'm getting a successful return value, but the procedure is not updating any rows.

Here's the procedure definition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE trans_data AS 
  PROCEDURE UPDATE_TRANS_BY_NAME(
    var_FName IN TRANSACTION.FIRST_NAME%type,
    var_LName IN TRANSACTION.LAST_NAME%type,
    var_DOB IN TRANSACTION.DOB%type,
    var_PolNum IN TRANSACTION.POLICY_NUMBER%type,
    var_TransStatus IN TRANSACTION.TRANS_STATUS%type,
    var_Comp IN TRANSACTION.COMPANY%type,
    var_LineOfBusiness IN TRANSACTION.LINE_OF_BUSINESS%type,
    var_PlanCode IN TRANSACTION.PLAN_CODE%type,
    var_AppDate IN TRANSACTION.APP_DATE%type,
    var_IssueDate IN TRANSACTION.ISSUE_DATE%type,
    var_FaceAmt IN TRANSACTION.FACE_AMT%type,
    var_PolicyStatus IN TRANSACTION.POLICY_STATUS%type,
    var_PaidAmt IN TRANSACTION.PAID_AMT%type,
    var_Return OUT VARCHAR2
  );  
END trans_data;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY trans_data AS 
  PROCEDURE UPDATE_TRANS_BY_NAME(
    var_FName IN TRANSACTION.FIRST_NAME%type,
    var_LName IN TRANSACTION.LAST_NAME%type,
    var_DOB IN TRANSACTION.DOB%type,
    var_PolNum IN TRANSACTION.POLICY_NUMBER%type,
    var_TransStatus IN TRANSACTION.TRANS_STATUS%type,
    var_Comp IN TRANSACTION.COMPANY%type,
    var_LineOfBusiness IN TRANSACTION.LINE_OF_BUSINESS%type,
    var_PlanCode IN TRANSACTION.PLAN_CODE%type,
    var_AppDate IN TRANSACTION.APP_DATE%type,
    var_IssueDate IN TRANSACTION.ISSUE_DATE%type,
    var_FaceAmt IN TRANSACTION.FACE_AMT%type,
    var_PolicyStatus IN TRANSACTION.POLICY_STATUS%type,
    var_PaidAmt IN TRANSACTION.PAID_AMT%type,
    var_Return OUT VARCHAR2)
  IS
  BEGIN
    UPDATE TRANSACTION
    SET
      POLICY_NUMBER = var_PolNum,
      TRANS_STATUS = var_TransStatus,
      COMPANY = var_Comp,
      LINE_OF_BUSINESS = var_LineOfBusiness,
      PLAN_CODE = var_PlanCode,
      APP_DATE = var_AppDate,
      ISSUE_DATE = var_IssueDate,
      FACE_AMT = var_FaceAmt,
      POLICY_STATUS = var_PolicyStatus,
      PAID_AMT = var_PaidAmt
    WHERE FIRST_NAME = var_FName
      AND LAST_NAME = var_LName
      AND DOB = var_DOB
      AND TRANS_STATUS = 'R'
      AND REASON_FOR_REVIEW = 'No Policy Match';
      commit;
      var_Return := 'PASS';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      var_Return := 'FAIL';
  END UPDATE_TRANS_BY_NAME;
END trans_data;
```

The row updates when I remove line "AND DOB = var_DOB" in the procedure.  I've tried changing the variable definition to a VARCHAR and using "AND DOB = to_date(var_DOB, 'DD-MON-YY')" with no success.  I also tried "AND TRUNC(DOB = var_DOB)", but it also did not work.

Here is the PHP code.  I have already verified all of the parameters being passed have values and are formatted correctly for the database datatypes.  I stripped out the code that does a previous query that populates some of the bound variables to cut out what is working.

```
function matchWSPolicy($policy, $trans, $status, $amount){

    include("../includes/DBConn.php");


    if ($Policy == ""){
        $message = 'Policy number does not match!';
        return $message;
    }

    $stmt = OCI_Parse($c,"begin ucs.trans_data.UPDATE_TRANS_BY_NAME(:var_FName, :var_LName, :var_DOB, :var_PolNum, 
        :var_TransStatus, :var_Comp, :var_LineOfBusiness, :var_PlanCode, :var_AppDate, :var_IssueDate, :var_FaceAmt, 
        :var_PolicyStatus, :var_PaidAmt, :var_Return); end;"); 
    OCI_BIND_BY_NAME($stmt,":var_FName",$FName);
    OCI_BIND_BY_NAME($stmt,":var_LName",$LName);
    OCI_BIND_BY_NAME($stmt,":var_DOB",$DOB);
    }
    else {
        $message = 'Policy matched, but a valid SSN or (first name, last name, date of birth) was not returned from the WS database';
}   

    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_PolNum",$Policy);
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_TransStatus",$status); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_Comp",$ComCode); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_LineOfBusiness",$LineOfBusiness); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_PlanCode",$Plan); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_AppDate",$AppDate); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_IssueDate",$IssueDate); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_FaceAmt",$FaceAmount); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_PolicyStatus",$PolStatus); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_PaidAmt",$amount); 
    OCI_Bind_By_Name($stmt,":var_Return",$return, 4); 

    if ($message == ''){
        oci_execute($stmt);
        oci_commit($c);
    }
    else{
        $message = 'Record not successfully updated.';
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I also tried "AND TRUNC(DOB = var_DOB)" - but did you try: "AND TRUNC(DOB) = to_date(var_DOB, 'DD-MON-YY')" ?

Comment: Yep.  That also did not work for me.

Comment: what do you get when you dump the DOB var? make sure your comparison value is exactly like the format of the date in the DOB var.  At least you know the problem is in the comparison of the date. Try this http://www.dba-oracle.com/f_to_date.htm

Comment: I'm getting var_DOB from a separate database query, and it is returning a DD-MON-YY format.  It is also the same value as what I see in the database row I'm updating.  I just tried changing that format to MM-DD-YY, then using to_date on the where clause, but that did not work.

Comment: What's the type of the column TRANSACTION.DOB?  Also, you might try "AND TRUNC(DOB) = TRUNC(var_DOB)", just for fun.

Comment: One other question, as I'm quite unfamiliar with PHP and OCI_Parse: are you really supposed to pass an anonymous PL/SQL block to this routine (i.e. function call within a BEGIN..END block)?  It looks odd to me, based on how other systems call stored procedures, but then there are many odd things in this world... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it has been over a year, but I had to come back to this project.  The answer was having to convert both values to dates even though the database value was already a date.

`AND to_date(DOB, 'DD-MON-YY') = to_date(var_DOB, 'DD-MON-YY')`

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE statement which affects zero rows is still be a successful one, because *it hasn't raised an exception*.  So you may want to test for `SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0` or `SQL%NOTFOUND` and hurl your own user-defined exception to simulate a failure.

As for why no rows are being updated the explanation is quite straightforward.  You say  yourself:

> 'The row updates when I remove line "AND DOB = var_DOB" in the
>   procedure.'

So clearly there are *no rows in the table* which match on Date of Birth plus the other criteria.  Apparently you think that's not the case, but I'm afraid it is.  So, either the database doesn't hold the exact data you think it does or your PHP isn't passing the precise value you think it does.  Only you are in a position to discover which option applies.

Probably the format mask is obscuring the source of your trouble.  For instance, you have tested a date format of 'DD-MON-YY'.  What happens when you explicitly include the century i.e. 'DD-MON-YYYY'?  What values for century does your table have?